# how to translate to rails query?

Tags: sql, mysql, ruby-on-rails

Ruby 2.3.8

Rails 5.0.0.1

I have problems translate to rails query.

I have a query which is finding duplicate data:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM (SELECT date, code, count(*) AS cnt FROM customers WHERE date >= '2021-01-01' GROUP BY date, code) p WHERE p.cnt > 1;
```

and I also would like to print for checking the result with logger but it doesn't work in rails batch.

Comment: It is unclear what result you are looking for as this will only return a single unnamed column containing an Integer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need `having` if I understand the question correctly:

```rb
Customer.where("date >= '2021-01-01'").having('count(*) > 1').group(:date, :code)
```

Comment: This will return a `Hash` of `{[date,code] => number}` rather than a count of all of them , although you could use `size` afterwards to solve that.

Comment: Thanks, @Vasily Kolesnikov. Helped me a lot. I got `Customer.where("date >= '2021-01-01'").select("date, code, count(*) as cnt").group("date, code").having("cnt > 1").select("count(*)")`